# How to populate a vector/list with all derived classes of a base class

Tags: c++

I would like to get a vector/list of derived class pointers (one corresponding to each derived class from an abstract base class) given the base class name, for instance.

Comment: You want to get a vector of derived pointers from *what input*?

Comment: This question is not answerable in its current form.

Comment: Are you asking, given an object, for a list of pointers to the various levels of class derivation of that object?  ie.  Foo*, DerivedFoo*, MoreDerivedFoo*.  Note that all these pointers will have the same value.

Comment: Edited the question slightly - hope its somewhat clearer now.

Comment: @Miller et al: Closing the question seems reasonable and would've sufficed, right? But why the darn downvote to go with it? Oh well, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

So to do exactly what you seems to want to do

```
#include <list>

class BaseObject { };

class Dinosaur : public BaseObject { };

class Hammer : public BaseObject { };

void
myFunction() {
  std::list<BaseObject*> myList;
  myList.push_back(new Dinosaur());
  myList.push_back(new Hammer());
}
```

Note that the objects in the list won't free by themselves when the list will be destroyed. Either you have to do manually (Iterating over the list and calling *delete*), either look on something a bit complex if you are a C++ beginner, *auto_ptr*, and the magic world of the smart pointers ^^

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, this is indeed the obvious solution, but I was hoping there was a way to avoid having to populate the list myself, using some run time features of the C++ compiler, perhaps?

Comment: @user545591: No such feature exists.

Comment: C++ philosophy is to do the least possible things behind the scene at runtime ! More dynamic, behind-the-scene-runtime-magic can be Objective C. Or if you want to go full force in that direction, Python, Ruby, Lisp...

Comment: It's not a good idea to put `auto_ptr`s into a std::list...

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a pointer to a class.  A class is just a specification for an object.  You only have something to point to once an object is created by instantiating the class.

If you have the following classes:

```
class FooBase {};
class DerivedFoo : public FooBase {};
class MoreDerivedFoo : public DerivedFoo {};
```

you can then create an object of type `MoreDerivedFoo` and point to it using a pointer of any of those types.

```
MoreDerivedFoo mdf = new MoreDerivedFoo();
FooBase* p1 = &mdf;
DerivedFoo* p2 = &mdf;
MoreDerivedFoo* p3 = &mdf;
```

Obviously each of these pointers will contain the same memory address.

Comment: @Cooper: Not quite what I was hoping for. But I realized from responses below that this is not so trivial. So please ignore for now.